# SublimeText3 with Python3 and Anaconda-ST3 plugin

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3, sublime-anaconda

I have been trying to follow Dan Bader's setup and he uses SublimeLinter with Flake8 and Anaconda Plug-in (not the distro). The functionality I can't achieve is the docstring popup and I noticed it is because my Sublime Text 3 is not noticing my Python3. I installed Python3 via homebrew.

```
which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

This is what I want to achieve: [image]

This is what I am actually getting:
[image]

On the settings for Anaconda plug-in in Sublime Text 3 you can either but the full path or just Python3 (according to most comments I have seen). But the reality is that God knows what Sublime Text 3 actually has for it's path. Some people mentioned that lanuching sublime from the commmand line would inherit you bash path but that did not work either. So in summary I get an error if I use just python3 in the settings and if I used the full path it just doesn't work.

On Anaconda.sublime-settings

```
{
    "python_interpreter": "python3",
}
```

Error with the above settings:

[image]

On Anaconda.sublime-settings, when using full path like below, nothing happened.

```
{
    "python_interpreter": "/usr/local/bin/python3",
}
```

Comment: You need to save your file before you can run it.

Comment: The autocompletion with docstrings doesn't work regardless. Not trying to run the file just trying to get the appropriate behavior on ST3 with anaconda plugin.